# AngularJs - how to know if controller finished initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a service which loads a file and then uses the controller in order to update the view.
if i use this.loadListAsync then the broadcast is useless because the controller does not exist yet, on the other hand if i use the $emit approach it works well by i feel im missing something here and that $emit is not for that purpose

```js
var mod= angular.module('mod1', []);
mod.service('modModel', ['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {

// here is how i know the controller finished initialization
    $rootScope.$on('modController', function(ev, data){
        data.loadListAsync();
    })

     this.loadListAsync = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'mainapp/dashboardList.js',
            type:'GET',
            cache:false,
            dataType: "script",
            success :this.broadcast
        })
    }

    this.broadcast= function(){
        this.list = list; // list is loaded from the async call
        $rootScope.$broadcast('modModel::list', list);
    }

//  this.loadListAsync(); // this line is not working because the controller is not initialized yet

}]);

mod.controller('filtersController',  ['$scope',  'sharedData', 'angularLoad','modModel', function ($scope, sharedData, angularLoad, modModel) {

    $scope.$on(''modModel::list', function(event, list) {

        $scope.list = list;
        doThings();
    });

    $scope.$emit('modController',modModel)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices, one is the $emit approach. You can refine it further by passing a unique event name (e.g. "loaded::") to be sure you are getting the right notification. And register the handler when you get the notification. The $on provides the unregister function as return value of $on. See the return value of $on here [angular doc for $on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

But why not simply pass a callback function. You can include a "this" context and then invoke as in `xyz.call(this_var, ... callback params)` inside `this.broadcast`?